# creating columnar tables in memsql

Tags: singlestore, columnstore

Im interested in studying columnar store in memsql. Im trying to create columnar tables. The query I used is,

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
    stud_id INT,
    stud_group INT,
    joining_date DATETIME,
    KEY (`stud_group`) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
    );
```

But the query throws me error at `clustered columnstore`. I don't know what leads to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the comma after `COLUMNSTORE`. It should be

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
    stud_id INT,
    stud_group INT,
    joining_date DATETIME,
    KEY (`stud_group`) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
    );
```

UPDATE: apparently not. Then the only reason it can happen is if you are using old version of MemSQL (before 4.0).

To see the version of MemSQL, run `SELECT @@memsql_version`.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT @@memsql_version`? The syntax you use was introduced in MemSQL 4.0. If the version is lower, you need to download the latest community edition, or upgrade, if you have a license.

Comment: version 5.6.19-0 is what im using.

Comment: The last version of MemSQL is `4.0`. `5.6.19` sounds like a version of MySQL. Where do you see that version?

Comment: i ran select version();

Comment: If it returned `5.6.19`, it is very likely that you are connected to MySQL, not to MemSQL. What happens when you run `SELECT @@memsql_version`?

Comment: this error i got. ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'memsql_version'. seems im connected to mysql. how do i connect to memsql?

Comment: First make sure MemSQL is running (`ps ax | grep memsqld`, should return two processes besides the grep itself). If it is, run `mysql -u root -h 0 -P3306`, then check again if it is MemSQL or MySQL.